# Callback and Promises : cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to write some code and it work but i ran into a problem where `bcrypt` makes use of callback and i am trying to resolve it with promise. Here is the code:

```
`UserSchema.statics.findByData = function(username,password) {
   var User = this;
   User.findOne({username}).then((user) => {
       if(!user){
         return Promise.reject();
       }

      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,res) => {
          if(res){
            resolve(user);
          }else {
            reject();
          }
        });
      });
   });
};`
```

I call this function from here :

```
User.findByData(body.username,body.password).then((user) => {
      res.send(user);
  }).catch((e) => {
      res.status(400).send();
  });
```

I get an error: `Cannot read property 'then ' of undefined.

Why i am getting this error?

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `findByData`, thus it's `undefined`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the first comment you need to return `User.findOne` which will be `promise`. So no need to create another `promise`. whenever you will return, `then` will be called with the returned value. You can use `Promise.reject()` and `Promise.resolve()` to call `catch` and `then` respectively as well.

```
UserSchema.statics.findByData = function(username,password) {
   var User = this;
   return User.findOne({username}).then((user) => {
       if(!user){
         Promise.reject('No user found');
       }
       bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,res) => {
         if(res){
           Promise.resolve(user);
         }else {
           Promise.reject(err);
         }
       });
   });
};
```